# permission to write in root/usr/share/kde4/apps

Tags: permissions, themes, root, su

i am trying to just do basic theming.. there isnt an install button for "Desktop Theme" so i am trying to copy the files to root/usr/share/kde4/apps/desktoptheme but get access denied message every time.. i tried changing permissions via properties then tried getting permissions using terminal and neither has led to any success... it would be most helpful if someone could tell me how to get total root permissions any time that i should need them as i know that kubuntu has these files as read only to protect more inexperienced users, like myself.. but this is how i learn... a lot of reading and trial and error..... any help is greatly appreciated.. thanks

Comment: which command did you used to copy files into your root directory?